# dropdown menus stacking onto one another

Tags: css

I really need help in displaying the drop-down sub-menus correctly in my website as soon as possible.

The sub-menus in my drop-down menu is **stacking over one another**.

I want those sub-menus to be displayed vertically.

How do I fix this?

Here is my code :

```css
div#nav_menu-2{
   float: left!important;
}

div.menu-secondary-container{
   display: block;
    background-color: #f3e6ff;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: visible;
 position: static;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul{
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
 /*position: relative;*/
 display: inline-block;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li a{
   display: block;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 12pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: purple;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:hover{
 background-color: lightgray;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:active{
 background-color: hotpink;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:link{
 color: darkpurple;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:visited{
 color: lightpurple;
}

.active{
 background-color: dimgray;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li li{
   display:none;
   clear: both;
   overflow: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
    position:absolute;
   
}

div#nav_menu-2 ul li li a{
 background-color: lightgray;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 min-width: 160px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_menu-2" class="header-widget widget_nav_menu header-widget-1 header-widget-num-1">
<div class="menu-secondary-container">
  <ul id="menu-secondary" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-     type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-115">
      <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/services/">Services</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-126">
          <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/background/">Background</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-129">
      <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/market-survey-reports/">Market Survey Reports</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-131">
      <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/behind-the-scene/">Behind the scene</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
  <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-116">
    <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/about-us/">About Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-128" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-128">
      <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/goals-and-objectives/">Goals and Objectives</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130">
      <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/social-need-assessment-study/">Social Need Assessment Study</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-117" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117">
  <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use `position: absolute` on `div#nav_menu-2 ul ul`

Answer (score 2):

You made the mistake of hiding the submenu `<li>` instead of the submenu `<ul>`. Other than that, your code was mostly working.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rkwcty1u/

You will notice now on `:hover` it shows the `<ul>` instead of the multiple `<li>`. The submenu `<ul>` is also positioned `absolute`, with the parent `<li>` being position `relative` so it contains it properly.

Comment: Actually, It worked for me but only when i removed position: relative from (div#nav_menu-2 ul li). I don't know why but whenever there is position: relative in (div#nav_menu-2 ul li), the dropdown submenus seem to hide behind the header image of  my website.  Also, have you noticed that when you hover over parent element and as soon as to try to hover over the submenus sometimes they just disappear quickly?  and thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below code to your **CSS** and modified `padding` and `line-height` in `div#nav_menu-2 ul li a`.

```
div#nav_menu-2 ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li:hover a {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```css
div#nav_menu-2 {
  float: left;
}
div.menu-secondary-container {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f3e6ff;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul {
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: purple;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:active {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:link {
  color: darkpurple;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li a:visited {
  color: lightpurple;
}
.active {
  background-color: dimgray;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li li {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
  float: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li li a {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  min-width: 160px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
}
div#nav_menu-2 ul li:hover a {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_menu-2" class="header-widget widget_nav_menu header-widget-1 header-widget-num-1">
  <div class="menu-secondary-container">
    <ul id="menu-secondary" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-     type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-115">
        <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/services/">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-126">
            <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/background/">Background</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-129">
            <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/market-survey-reports/">Market Survey Reports</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-131">
            <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/behind-the-scene/">Behind the scene</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-116">
        <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/about-us/">About Us</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-128" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-128">
            <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/goals-and-objectives/">Goals and Objectives</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130">
            <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/social-need-assessment-study/">Social Need Assessment Study</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-117" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117">
        <a href="http://localhost/careerdishanepal/contact/">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```